# Why can't jest mock my functions correctly?

Tags: jestjs, svelte, sveltekit, ts-jest

I'm creating a sveltkit app, and I'm trying to test if **the load function** is running and all of the items from that function call are being rendered on the screen. I tried to mock the entire module and adjust the load function to return some dummy data, but when I try to run the tests I get error saying: **received value must be a mock or spy function**

**Test:**

```
import { describe, jest } from "@jest/globals";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/svelte";
import Page from "./+page.svelte";
import { load } from "./+page.server";
jest.mock("./+page.server", () => {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual("./+page.server") as {}
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...originalModule,
        load: jest.fn(() => ({
            agents: [
                { uuid: "", displayName: "a", description: "", displayIcon: "", fullPortrait: "", background: "", role: { displayName: "", displayIcon: "" }, abilities: [] },
                { uuid: "", displayName: "b", description: "", displayIcon: "", fullPortrait: "", background: "", role: { displayName: "", displayIcon: "" }, abilities: [] },
                { uuid: "", displayName: "c", description: "", displayIcon: "", fullPortrait: "", background: "", role: { displayName: "", displayIcon: "" }, abilities: [] },
            ]
        }))
    };
})
describe("testing the home page", () => {
    it("should load and render all agents on the page", () => {
        // @ts-ignore
        render(Page)
        expect(load).toBeCalled()
        expect(screen.getAllByTestId("agent-a")).toHaveLength(1)
        expect(screen.getAllByTestId("agent-b")).toHaveLength(1)
        expect(screen.getAllByTestId("agent-c")).toHaveLength(1)
    })
})
```

**Page, just the script tag**

```
export let data;
const agents = data?.agents || [];
```

**Page server (responsible to provide the data to the page), the function that im trying to mock**

```
import valorant from "../lib/services/valorant" 
export async function load() {
    const agents = await valorant.getAgents()
    return { agents } 
}
```

When I try to run the test I get:

```
  ● testing the home page › should load and render all agents on the page

    expect(received).toBeCalled()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function load]

      22 |         // @ts-ignore
      23 |         render(Page)
    > 24 |         expect(load).toBeCalled()
```

expected jest to transform the function into a mock function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the issue. As I'm using ESM i have to use a different approach, instead of using the `jest.mock` function I had to use `jest.unstable_mockModule` function, and then the module has to be imported with the import function:

```
import { describe, jest } from "@jest/globals";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/svelte";
import Page from "./+page.svelte";
jest.unstable_mockModule("./+page.server", () => {

    return {
        __esModule: true,
        load: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(({
            agents: [
                { uuid: "", displayName: "a", description: "", displayIcon: "", fullPortrait: "", background: "", role: { displayName: "", displayIcon: "" }, abilities: [] },
                { uuid: "", displayName: "b", description: "", displayIcon: "", fullPortrait: "", background: "", role: { displayName: "", displayIcon: "" }, abilities: [] },
                { uuid: "", displayName: "c", description: "", displayIcon: "", fullPortrait: "", background: "", role: { displayName: "", displayIcon: "" }, abilities: [] },
            ],
        })))
    };
})

const { load } = await import("./+page.server")


describe("testing the home page", () => {
    it("should load and render all agents on the page", () => {
        render(Page)
        expect(load).toBeCalled()
        expect(screen.getAllByTestId("agent-a")).toHaveLength(1)
        expect(screen.getAllByTestId("agent-b")).toHaveLength(1)
        expect(screen.getAllByTestId("agent-c")).toHaveLength(1)

    })
})
```